# Dart Dio Package `DioError` `request` Object not defined

Tags: dart, dio

In the Dart Dio package documentation at https://pub.dev/packages/dio#handling-errors it describes how to handle errors:

```dart
try {
  //404
  await dio.get('https://wendux.github.io/xsddddd');
} on DioError catch (e) {
  // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
  // that falls out of the range of 2xx and is also not 304.
  if (e.response) {
    print(e.response.data)
    print(e.response.headers)
    print(e.response.request)
  } else {
    // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
    print(e.request)
    print(e.message)
  }
}
```

The code makes sense and gives me the options I need to understand what happened with my request, but the Dart Analysis tool in Android Studio (I'm working on a Flutter app) reacts violently to it.

I can fix many of the analyzer's complaints by adding null checks to the code as recommended by Android Studio:

```dart
try {
    var response = await dio.get(url, options: options);
    print('Response: $response');
    return response.data;
} on DioError catch (e) {
    // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
    // that falls out of the range of 2xx and is also not 304.
    if (e.response != null) {
      print(e.response!.data);
      print(e.response!.headers);
      print(e.response!.request);  <-- line 64
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
      print(e.request);  <-- line 67
      print(e.message);
    }
}
```

but the analyzer still complains about the `request` object:

```
error: The getter 'request' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>'. (undefined_getter at [particle_cloud] lib\src\particle.dart:64)
error: The getter 'request' isn't defined for the type 'DioError'. (undefined_getter at [particle_cloud] lib\src\particle.dart:67)
```

I'm assuming the DioError should have the appropriate request object defined, how do I get this code fixed so it runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their readme was not updated when the API changed. The equivalent to `request` in the new API is `requestOptions`. This can be easily found by looking in the [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/DioError-class.html).

```dart
print(e.requestOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I submitted a PR with the Dio team to fix the docs.